# boolean check with ternary operator in Ruby

Tags: ruby, boolean, ternary-operator

Having such code

```
def f(string)
     if string.start_with? 'a'
         return true
     else
         return false
     end
end
```

Trying to write `string.start_with? 'a' ? 'true' : 'false'` gives me warning
`warning: string literal in condition` and do not work as expected.
That is not question about given warning, but rather about correct syntax for ternary operators in Ruby
Question:
Is it possible to rewrite above code using ternary operator?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [warning: string literal in condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20867709/warning-string-literal-in-condition)

Comment: string.start_with?('a') ? 'true' : 'false'

Comment: the method `start_with?` return true or false, so why to use ternary op ? ;)

Comment: or just `string[0] == 'a'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just:

```
def f(string)
  string.start_with? 'a'
end
```

In your case ruby executes code in the next order:

```
string.start_with? ('a' ? true : false)
# expected
string.start_with?('a') ? 'true' : 'false'
```

Comment: It is simplified example, anyway `string.start_with?('a') ? 'true' : 'false'` is what I was looking for. Thank you for help!